# RMySQL: Error in as.character.default() :

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I am trying to use the following function in R:

```
 heritblup <-  function(name) {
      library(RMySQL)
      library(DBI)
      con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),
                       dbname ="mydab",
                       host      = "localhost",
                       port  = 3306,
                       user  = "root",
                       password = "")
      value1 <- 23;
      rss<- paste0 ("INSERT INTO namestable 
                    (myvalue, person) 
                    VALUES ('$value1', '",name,"')")
      rs <<- dbGetQuery (con, rss)
    }

heritblup("Tommy")
```

But I keep getting this error:

> Error in as.character.default()
>   :    no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector Called from:
>   as.character.default()

I tried to change the paste function to this:
rss<- paste0 ("INSERT INTO namestable 
                    (myvalue, person) 
                    VALUES ($value1, ",name,")")

the error persists;
 I have no idea whats wrong.
Please help

Comment: Are you trying to `insert` data in table or fetch data from table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of issues in code. I'm not sure if OP is attempting to `insert` records in database or fetch from database.

Assuming, based on query that he is expecting to insert data in database table.

The rule is that query should be prepared in `R` the way it will be executed in MySQL. Value replacement (if any) should be performed in `R` as MySQL engine will not have any idea about variables from `R`.

Hence, the query preparation steps should be done as:

```
rss <- sprintf("INSERT INTO namestable (myvalue, person) VALUES (%d, '%s')", value1, name)
# "INSERT INTO namestable (myvalue, person) VALUES (23, 'test')"
```

If data insert is goal then `dbGetQuery` is not right option per R documentation instead `dbSendStatement()` should be used for data manipulation. The reference from help suggest:

> However, callers are strongly encouraged to use dbSendStatement() for
>   data manipulation statements.

Based on that query execution line should be:

```
rs <- dbSendStatement(con, rss)
ret_val <- dbGetRowsAffected(rs)
dbClearResult(rs)
dbDisconnect(con)
return(ret_val)
```